# Align item horizontally in CSS and limit the space of scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have some panel with some item. There will be logo + labels, arranged horizontally. If there is an overflow-x, there will appear a scroll bar. If I put just the labels, all elements are aligned. But if I insert the image, they are no longer vertically aligned. Why?

**CSS** code:

```css
body {
   font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 color: #89867e;
 background: #f9f9f9;
}
.wrapper {
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 2em;
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: 300;
 max-height: 388px; 
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}

.internal {
  display: inline; 
 height: 164px;
 padding: .4em 1em; 
 border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 -webkit-border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 -moz-border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 -o-border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 color: rgba(249, 249, 249, .9);
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: 300;
 margin-right: 18px;
}
 

.wrapper a:nth-child(6n+1) { background: #e87352; }

.wrapper a:nth-child(6n+2) { background: #ebc85e; }

.wrapper a:nth-child(6n+3) { background: #3bbec0; }

.wrapper a:nth-child(6n+4) { background: #4ad585; }

.wrapper a:nth-child(6n+5) { background: rgb(27, 54, 71); }

.wrapper a:nth-child(6n+6) { background: rgb(21, 40, 54); }
 

.wrapper:nth-child(6n+1) { background: rgb(208, 101, 3); }

.wrapper:nth-child(6n+2) { background: rgb(233, 147, 26); }

.wrapper:nth-child(6n+3) { background: rgb(22, 145, 190); }

.wrapper:nth-child(6n+4) { background: rgb(22, 107, 162); }

.wrapper:nth-child(6n+5) { background: rgb(27, 54, 71); }

.wrapper:nth-child(6n+6) { background: rgb(21, 40, 54); }

.trasparente {
  background: transparent !important;
 padding: 0;
 border:none;
}

.logo {
 max-width: 318px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-right: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="internal trasparente"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/bar/8/86/744px-Siemens-logo_svg.png" class="logo" style="margin-top:20px" alt="logo"></a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 1</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 2</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 3</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 4</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 5</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 6</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 7</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 8</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 9</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 10</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 11</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 12</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 13</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 14</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 15</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 16</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 17</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 18</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 19</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 20</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 21</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 22</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 23</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 24</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 25</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 26</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 27</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 28</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 29</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 30</a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="internal trasparente"><img src="http://www.asborsoniww.com/media/tes_logo.png" class="logo" style="margin-top:20px" alt="logo"></a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 1</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 2</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 3</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 4</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 5</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 6</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 7</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 8</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 9</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 10</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 11</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 12</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 13</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 14</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 15</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 16</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 17</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 18</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 19</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 20</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 21</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 22</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 23</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 24</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 25</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 26</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 27</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 28</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 29</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 30</a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="" class="internal">item 1</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 2</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 3</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 4</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 5</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 6</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 7</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 8</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 9</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 10</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 11</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 12</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 13</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 14</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 15</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 16</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 17</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 18</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 19</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 20</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 21</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 22</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 23</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 24</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 25</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 26</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 27</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 28</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 29</a>
  <a href="" class="internal">item 30</a>
</div>
```

And there is the possibility to limit the length of the scroll-x, and add at the end of each panel "wrapper" (in the space just removed to the scroll) a right arrow (or any other elements)?

Comment: Just try removing  style="margin-top:20px" from logo element.

Comment: I will retrieve the images from json, so I will not know the exact size of logo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not using a **Bootstrap** component like those following for example?

http://www.bootply.com/d1xV5UTiqv

http://www.bootply.com/DKihet1ZM9

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: I wanted to try by myself